# Usage d’exclamatif à l'infinitif ou au conditionnel présent

Tags: sens, usage, exclamations

Je ne suis pas sûre que l’on puisse remplacer ces deux tournures comme elles expriment les mêmes sentiments de surprise.

> A: Tu as triché, non ?
>
> B: Moi, avoir triché ce jeu ! → moi, je tricherais !

et

> C: J’achèterais des chiffons !? → moi, avoir acheté des chiffons !?

Comment: Moi, avoir triché **à** ce jeu? Moi, acheter des chiffons?

Answer (score 2):

La différence principale c'est que le conditionnel présent fait référence à un comportement récurrent alors que l'auxilliaire + participe passé fait référence à un épisode seulement.

Cela dit, si vous aviez réellement utilisé un infinitif, comme:
« moi, tricher? » vs « moi, je tricherais ? »
Alors le sens est identique.